# Como cargar correctamente un widget en el Home screen

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-widget

Estoy tratando de crear un widget con información cargada desde un Sqlite.
El problema que tengo es que el widget en si no carga dicho contenido.
Adjunto código.

widget_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/widget_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

widget_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_symbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        tools:text="List Item"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Widget Provider

```
public class ToDoTickWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static final String UPDATE_MEETING_ACTION = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.example.edockh.EXTRA_ITEM";


static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stock_symbol, pendingIntent);

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
}
```

Servicio

```
public class ListViewWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new ListViewRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
```

y por ultimo el factory

```
public class ListViewRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private Intent intent;

    public ListViewRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent){
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    private void  initCursor(){
        if (cursor!=null){
            cursor.close();
        }
        final long identityToken = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        cursor = new ListFacade(context).RowsCursor();
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identityToken);    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initCursor();
        if (cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        initCursor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        System.out.println("--->"+cursor.getCount()+"<---");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.stock_symbol, cursor.getString(1));

        return remoteViews;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Como obtengo el cursor

```
public Cursor RowsCursor(){
        SQLiteDatabase conn = new SqliteHandler(context).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  conn.rawQuery("SELECT ROWID,* from TODO_LIST", null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Y el resultado del widget es quedar en blanco

[image: no carga la info]

Comment: ¿y no has visto que se muestra en el LogCat?, esto es super importante.

Comment: Por alguna razón, esa pregunta se hizo con una asociación a mi cuenta de google. pero encontré la solución. había que llamar al servicio en el "onUpdate".

Answer (score 0):

Hay que llamar al servicio en el **onUpdate** y modificar en el *app-provider* el tiempo de actualización del widget dependiendo de lo que se desee.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListViewWidgetService.class);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_listView,intent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views)
    }
}
```